# cp directory with permissions but not recursively

Tags: cp

I want to create an empty directory with some permissions and owned by user `apache:apache`. I could just `mkdir` it, `chown` it and `chmod` it, but in directory where I want to create it I have a directory with just the permissions and owner I need.

So I want to do sth like: `cp old_dir new_dir` but with permissions and owners.
To preserve the permissions option `-p` is used, so the command should be `cp -p old_dir new_dir`. But that one returns the error: `cp: omitting directory ‘field’`.

It would work with options `-rp` or better `-a` but `old_dir` contains some dirs and files and I just want to copy the empty directory.

I also tried using `--parents` option (`cp -p --parents old_dir new_dir`) which creates any missing intermediate directories but then I get this error: `cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory`.

How do I do that? (bonus points for not using `;` and `&&`)

Comment: `cp -p` does what you want, it omits the underlying directories. so just the files in that directory are copied over. I have a feeling this is not an answer to you question, but your question is unclear. Do you just want to copy the dir structure with original permissions?

Comment: Adding `-T` could help

Comment: @aairey I know `cp -p` does what it's supposed to but not what I want. I want to clone `old_dir` with all permissions and name `new_dir`.

Comment: @Niranjan It doesn't. Same errors.

Comment: So how many hours did you already spend on finding a solution that's not "mkdir; chmod; chown" ? 

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I obviously did mkdir+chmod+chown in the first place but just after that asked this question which took me 10 mins. Now I'll know how to do that in the future using only one command. :-)

Comment: Sorry but your question was not very clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `rsync` for that job.

```
rsync -av --exclude=/<old_dir>/* /<old_dir> /<new_dir>
```